# convert a list of dictionary in given format

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
Input_data=[{​​​'filename':'file_A','start_page':1,'end_page':3,'angle':90}​​​,{'filename':'file_A','start_page':6,'end_page':8,'angle':270}​​​,{'filename':'file_B','start_page':2,'end_page':3,'angle':90}​​​,{'filename':'file_B','start_page':5,'end_page':5,'angle':270}​​​]

output=[{​​​'filename':'file_A','page':1,'angle':90}​​​,
{​​​'filename':'file_A','page':2,'angle':90}​​​,{​​​'filename':'file_A','page':3,'angle':90}​​​,{​​​'filename':'file_A','page':6,'angle':270}​​​,{​​​'filename':'file_A','page':7,'angle':270}​​​,
```

{​​​'filename':'file_A','page':8,'angle':270}​​​,{​​​'filename':'file_B','page':2,'angle':90}​​​,
{​​​'filename':'file_B','page':3,'angle':90}​​​,{​​​'filename':'file_B','page':5,'angle':270}​​​]

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to do:

```
output = []
for d in Input_data:
    for i in range(d["start_page"], d["end_page"] + 1):
        output.append({'filename':d["filename"], 'page':i, 'angle':d["angle"]})

print(output)
```

Comment: I think the expected output needs to be till `d["end_page"]` so you need `range(d["start_page"], d["end_page"]+1)`